# Excel 2010 VLOOKUP simply not work as expected in window 8.1

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to copy another cell when some matching any cell value by using vlookup but it simply not work as well please check my below format.

**Result:** **#N/A**

```
=VLOOKUP(D77,OROBmc!B13:H50,1,1)
```

My Sheet which I want to use this formula

[image]
And Below is the sheet I that I try to copy the date value (column 5th)

[image]

Comment: your screenshot doesn't contain column headers, but it seems that you try to look for data in the second column. `VLOOKUP` can look for values in the first column of the range only. You may use `INDEX` and `MATCH` instead.

Comment: Should you give me some idea for using index and mathc

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is the DATE column 6 matched with column 2  Which is 4 difference starting at column C

```
=VLOOKUP(D77,OROBmc!C13:H50,4,0)
```

The FIRST column is C which is what it will match against

The Last parameter (0) means EXACT Match

Comment: Index and match would be 
=INDEX(OROBmc!F13:F50, Match(D77,OROBmc!C13:C50,0))